# The term Oedipus complex explains

Tags: traducción

I want to translate [this sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus_complex) into Spanish:

> The term Oedipus complex explains the emotions and ideas that the mind keeps in the unconscious, via dynamic repression, that concentrates upon a child's desire to have sexual relations with the parent of the opposite sex .

My attempt:

> El término "complejo de Edipo" explica las emociones e ideas que la mente mantiene en el inconsciente , a través de la represión dinámica que se concentra en el deseo de un niño para tener relaciones sexuales con el progenitor del sexo opuesto.

Is my translation correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it sounds good. Some extra commas or dots would help reading it out loud!

Comment: 10/10. I think is perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say "... que se concentra en el deseo de un niño **de** tener relaciones ...".

One reference I've found to support the use of "*de*": [Deseo sexual](http://www.asexuality.org/sp/wiki/index.php?title=Deseo_sexual)

I believe using "*para*" indicates "for whom", more than "with". As in "*en el deseo de un niño de salud **para** su padre*"

Comment: Thanks. Is using para incorrect?

Comment: Yes. "para" is not correct in your context. You should use "de".  Guiseppe's explanation and examples are correct.